# Determining the difference of row elements in 3d array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to know if there is 3 d array say :

```
int a[2][3][2]={{{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}},{{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}};
```

How And what does the expression a[1]-a[0] calculate?

Comment: `a[1] - a[0]` tries to subtract two `int**`'s. I believe it's a compiler error, and it definitely isn't what you're asking for.

Comment: If you don't go through the 3 dimensions, you will just do pointer arithmetic

Comment: how much do you have to add to `a[0]` to get to `a[1]`?

Comment: Do you want find the difference between all the elements of row1 and row2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does the expression a[1]-a[0] calculate?

It calculates the difference between the pointers to which `a[1]` and `a[0]` decay if use as operators to the arithemtic operator `-`.

Comment: sure? `int a[2][3][2]={{{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}},{{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}};
  printf("%ld\n", a[1]-a[0]);` prints `3`

Comment: Your description is `&a[1]-&a[0]`.

Comment: Ouch .. yes. Removed the non-sense addtion from my answer. @mch

Comment: Cleaned up. @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a[2][3][2]={{{1,2},{9,8},{3,7}},{{2,2},{1,4},{5,4}}};
    printf("%d\n", (int)(a[1]-a[0]));//3
    int (*b1)[2] = a[1];//b1 point to {1,2}
    int (*b0)[2] = a[0];//b0 point to {2,2}
    printf("%d\n", (int)(b1-b0));//3
    printf("%d\n", (int)(&a[1]-&a[0]));//1

    return 0;
}
/*
int a[2][3][2]
a <-> int (*)[3][2]
a[n] <-> int [3][2] <-> int (*)[2]
&a[n] <-> int (*)[3][2]
*/
```

Answer (score -3):

Always think of multidimensional arrays as a grid/table. 
Here is that same array split up into sections:

a[2] = Container containing 2 2D arrays
 [3] = Container containing 3 arrays
 [2] = Actual data values

What data you are accessing all depends on how many brackets you are putting when you call the array, for example:
a[1] = {{2, 2},{1, 4},{5, 4}}
a[1][1] = {1, 4}
a[1][1][1] = 4
The expression a[1] - a[0] can't be done because you are subtracting an array by another array, which means you are using objects that point to data, not actual data. But, it literally evaluates to:

a[1] = {{2, 2},{1, 4},{5, 4}} and
a[0] = {{1, 2},{9, 8},{3, 7}} so,
{{2, 2},{1, 4},{5, 4}} - {{1, 2},{9, 8},{3, 7}}

Comment: no, it subtracts the addresses relative to the object size, so the result is `3` in this example.

Comment: The arrays `a[1]` and `a[0]` decay to `int (*)[2]`, they can be subtracted.

Comment: @nilpointerinception yes, for you. It tells you that your last paragraph is not correct.

Comment: Adding and substracting pointers to the same object (array here) is perfectly valid. For the result read about pointer arithmetics.

Comment: @alk thnk you...wanted to know y 3.Got it ..No compilation errors.